# Why is this pattern not working with knockout validation? (delimited zip codes)

Tags: javascript, regex, knockout.js, knockout-validation

This clearly works on every regex tester I can find, as well as with jquery validation and MVC attributes. What am I missing? I have tried the literal as well as the RegExp but the most I get is validating the first 5 are numeric but other than that either fails anything else or nothing else.

example:
https://regex101.com/r/gS0wP0/1

```
regex: /(\d{5}(\s?)*,?(\s?)*)+/

ko.observable().extend({ pattern: { message: 'Test Message', params:/(\d{5}(\s?)*,?(\s?)*)+/ } });
```

Comment: I have not yet worked with knockout but how about simplifying your regex: `/\d{5}(\s*,\s*\d{5})+/`

Comment: The MVC regex attibute implicitly checks for full length match starting from the first index. So it working essentially with the pattern `/^(\d{5}(\s?)*,?(\s?)*)+$/`... however the KO validation only working with the provided pattern without any additional logic.

Comment: @nemesv, that was is, i was not aware that was happening, thank you! if you add this as an answer i'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `RegularExpressionAttribute` which is used in ASP.NET MVC implicitly checks for a full length match starting from the first index.

So it is essentially converting your the pattern to: `/^(\d{5}(\s?)*,?(\s?)*)+$/`

However the KO validation is only working with the provided pattern without any additional logic, there you need to manually add the `^` and `$` to match for the whole line:

```
ko.observable().extend({ 
    pattern: { 
       message: 'Test Message', 
       params:/^(\d{5}(\s?)*,?(\s?)*)+$/ } 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear to me what you're trying to accomplish here. You say

> the most I get is validating the first 5 are numeric

I think, from the title, that you want a comma delimited list of zipcodes so your regex test you linked should fail because of the alpha characters.

I think this regex may work for you

```
\s*(\d{5})\s*(,\s*\d{5})*
```

It's a bit generous with spacing but to be honest I'd run a regex replace on the string to strip down spaces first. That would look something like `string.replace(/\s+/g,"")` and then your regex can look something like this.

```
(\d{5})(,\d{5})*
```

Finally, with both regexes (space-padded or space-removed), you can change the asterisk at the end to set of numbers if you want to control how many zipcodes can be in the list.

If you wanted 1-5 zipcodes, you would say `(\d{5})(,\d{5}){0,4}`. If you wanted 3-6 zipcodes, you would say `(\d{5})(,\d{5}){2,5}`, note that the range numbers are one less than the range you desire because the first part of the regex requires 1.

If you wanted simply 2 or more, you can change the final asterisk to simply `+`.

Finally, in any case, if you want to match the whole string, which you probably do, you should wrap it with `^` and `$` (start and end of string respectively) like so `^(\d{5})(,\d{5})*$`

Comment: this is great, i like the idea of stripping it down, it does make the regex much cleaner and I like the ability to limit the amount.

Comment: @Tony if you want the entire string too follow this form you should prefix with ^ and suffix with $. I'll append that to my answer later